# Eclipse Neon Content Assist has no proposals for JavaScript

Tags: eclipse, javascript, autocomplete, web-development

Bottom Line Up Front: Eclipse Neon content assist (Ctrl+space) does not offer any proposals for my JavaScript code. Here's a screenshot:

[image: (Screenshot)]

Here is what I've checked so far:

1. JSDT has been installed
2. "JavaScript resources" include ECMASciptBuilt-In Library, ECMA 3 Browser Support Library, jQuery
3. The project's Include path has ECMAScipt Built-In Library, ECMA 3
   Browser Support Library, jQuery, and JavaScript Web Project support
4. Eclipse's JavaScript Content Assist is enabled and includes Basic
   proposals, Other JavaScript Proposals, Template Proposals, and word
   Proposals.
5. I changed the content assist from ctrl+space to ctrl+0 to
   check whether ctrl+space had been hijacked
6. Content assist DOES work with regular Java (in a different project)
7. I tried reset to defaults under Content Assist > Advanced
8. JavaScript facet is selected for the project
9. .js files and .jsp files are stored in folders that are under folders that are designated as source folders in the project properties under JavaScript > Include Path
10. This is also an issue in Mars 2.
11. I've run through the steps listed here for configuring content assist: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_content_assist.htm

The content assist isn't even proposing functions that are defined within the same .js file.  How can I get Eclipse's content assist to propose elements correctly?

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_content_assist.htm

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Sara.  I've actually reviewed that page already, and unfortunately it did not address my issue.

Comment: It has been a few months since this question was raised, but js content-assist is still lacking in neon release. I've tried with all kinds of projects including `dynamic web project`, `static web project` and even `javascript project`, but nowhere is it working.

Comment: @sara The linked manual is really great, but works only upto the mars release. The neon release has some specific problems due to which the content assist isn't working in that.